# Modify parts of numpy array in for loop

Tags: python, numpy

I want to loop through the first dimension of an array, do a computation on each sub-array, and assign the result back to the array.  It doesn't work when I use the "pythonic" form `for b in bob:` -- but I know that it ought to, because if I modify `b` in place it actually changes the matrix.

Is there a way to carry out the assignment in the middle "for" loop, below?

```
import numpy as np

bob = np.arange(0, 60).reshape((3, 4, 5))

print(bob)

# This does not change elements in bob
for b in bob:
    b = b + 3
    
print(bob)

# This does change elements in bob
for b in bob:
    b += 3
    
print(bob)
```

Comment: `b = b + 3` assigns a new object to the variable `b`.  It does  not modify the the original `b`.  This is a basic Python iterative behavior.   `b[:] = b+3` should work like the `b+=`.

Comment: That works!  You should make it an answer so I can check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b = b + 3` assigns a new object to the variable `b`. It does not modify the the original `b`. This is a basic Python iterative behavior. `b[:] = b+3` should work like the `b+=`